# DatabindingException on web service binding

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

Any idea about the exception? I cant bind a JAX-WS service due exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: ''{0}''
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory.newContext(JAXBRIContextFactory.java:90)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:167)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:203)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:176)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:176)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:309)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:59)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:43)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:875)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:892)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:855)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:435)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
```

The project is running in Ecplipse, JDK 1.8.
All artifacts generated by :

```
/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 3.2.0
 * 2018-03-28T18:06:56.868+02:00
 * Generated source version: 3.2.0
 * 
 */
@WebService(targetNamespace = "...........", name = "IDocuments")
```

Classes from wsdl are generated without errors.
Note that with SoapUi I'm able to bind and use this service and couple of other @WebService, generated in the same way, work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Solved...
The problem was a conflict on multiple wsdl generation.

The last generated wsdl deploys its factory classes.
On this way requests and responses was created by the wrong context and the service throws IllegalArgumentException.

Issue fixed by customizing package for each generated wsdl

Comment: please, can you inform how you got around this, I know it was an age ago